# Is the compositum morally equivalent to the sum?

Tags: field-theory

Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are (algebraically independent) algebraic numbers and that $K$ is the compositum of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta).$ Is it true that $\alpha+\beta$ is (a rational multiple of) a root of the minimal polynomial of $K$? (If not, does something similar hold?)

This isn't for a class, I'm just trying to understand the notion of a field compositum and observe that this seems to hold in the examples I've tried.

Comment: minimal polynomials aren't unique, in fact there are infinitely many different choices, even if you demand monic.

Comment: What do you mean by «algebraically independent»? Under the usual definition, that would imply they are not algebraic, and in that case it may well be the case that $\alpha+\beta$ is also not algebraic. On the other hand, what do you mean by «the minimal polynomial of $K$? $K$, being a field, does not have a minimal polynomial according to the usual terminology.

Comment: Minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm not actually sure what the right notion of independence is here (I changed it several times before submitting, and clearly made a bad choice); I'm trying to avoid situations like $\alpha=-\beta$ where $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta)=\mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: Obligatory complaint that the compositum of two algebraic extensions isn't well-defined unless either 1) you fix an embedding of them in a bigger extension or 2) they are normal. (For example, what is the compositum of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]/(\alpha^3 - 2)$ with $\mathbb{Q}[\beta]/(\beta^3 - 2)$? Well, it depends on whether, with a fixed choice of embedding $\sigma$ of both extensions into $\mathbb{C}$, we have $\frac{\sigma(\alpha)}{\sigma(\beta)} = 1$ or a nontrivial cube root of unity.)

Comment: I've edited my answer, is that case one of them you want not to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: (A Counterexample )**
Consider the splitting field of the polynomial $x^3-2$, it is $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i\sqrt{3})$.

Now if $\mathbb{F}$ is not generated by $\sqrt[3]{2}+i\sqrt{3}$ you have a counterexample, else consider the extension $\mathbb{E}=\mathbb{Q}(i(1-\sqrt{3}))$ and consider the compositum $\mathbb{EF}$.

We want to prove that $\mathbb{EF}$ is not generated by $\sqrt[3]{2}+i\sqrt{3}+i(1-\sqrt{3})=\sqrt[3]{2}+i$, but now this is obvious because $[\mathbb{EF}:\mathbb{Q}]=12$ and, conversely, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+i)$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$, that has degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, after the counterexample, I think the following theorem can give you some interesting ideas about extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

> **Theorem** Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Consider the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$. Then there exist an open dense subset $U \subset \mathbb{Q}$ (in the Zariski topology) such that $\forall u \in U$ the element $\alpha + u \beta$ is a primitive element for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$.

So the sum might not generate the compositum of the two extension, but this is a "rare" evenience: now you know there exist only a finite number of "unlucky" rational $u$ (such that $\alpha + u \beta$ doesn't generate $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$ ).

Finally an observation: I think this holds for an arbitrary field $k$ just requiring  $k(\alpha, \beta)$ separable over $k$, but I'm not sure. I know a constructive demonstration of this theorem by metods of Commutative Computational Algebra but I don't remember very well if there are strenght hypotesis on the base field.

Comment: I think you want to say “So the sum might not generate” in the third paragraph. The word you  used might lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me everything I wanted: a counterexample, an explanation, and (a hint toward) what is needed to make it work.